# Particular application design Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm posting here in order to know if it was possible to make this design in Android :

[image]

If yes, could you help me how to do it (Just Guidelines).

Thank you

**EDIT :**

if I use only one Relative Layout I have this xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_cross"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="F1\n" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="Left\nbutton" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right\nbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp"
        android:text="Bottom\nbutton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But declaring static dp is very bad and it isn't good to apply on all devices.. 
My xml code is shit ?

Do I have to get width and height screen of the device programmatically and set my buttons positions programmatically too ?

May be I could use this picture in Background and bind buttons on it ? (But how ?)

Comment: yes they are buttons.

Comment: This should be doable with one RelativeLayout only. What you would need is screen sized background image with the cross for main RelativeLayout. Then with padding adjust bounds so that ImageButtons (or how ever you want to create them) will take correct places when setting them with ``layout_centerHorizontal``/``Vertical`` and ``layout_alignParentRight``/``Left``/``Bottom``/``Top``. At least you should get something very close.

Comment: Why not just place this image on the screen? Or use a 9-patch? Then the buttons can switch selected drawables using a selector.

Comment: This is very interesting Phil, I would have to do like that but I don't know how to bind them 4 buttons with my code .. do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a `RelativeLayout` and add the four buttons in it. Android supports adding custom fonts to your app and you will be able to set the button's font as well, you just need the font file. See [here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2013/04/set-custom-font-on-android-from-assets.html) or [here](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-using-custom-fonts/) an example.
You will need the buttons background just as a white/red ring with transparent background.
You can place the buttons inside the `RelativeLayout` using margin properties (`layout_marginLeft`/`Right`/`Top`/`Bottom`) see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) other properties.
The buttons text should have two lines (see `android:lines` xml property for a `Button`).

Good luck! I hope it helps ;).

Comment: It seems to be fine, at least if it seems ok visually for you.. The thing with the multiple screens is that you can make this layout in diferent layout folders containing the -small -normal -large.. sufixes and so you can add or smaller the dp values according to your needs. This way the system will pick the best matching xml layout for the current screen